# "In case you're living under a rock" in Japanese

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese

I'm wondering how this phrase could be translated into Japanese in a way that isn't rude but keeps being funny to Japanese readers. Please give the literal meaning of the Japanese words too.

It's often used online to once again introduce a subject that the author assumes readers are tired of hearing about.

> In case you're living under a rock, this app allows you to ...

Comment: As far as I know with respect to other languages, the end result is likely to be something completely different -- For example, Spanish might sometimes use the phrase (lit. translated as) "You've invented powder" in jest; Russian might use "Did you just come from the mountains?" and so forth.

So, clarifying, I think the question is really about a phrase that particularly means "introducing a very basic thing to someone who probably should know about it, but likely doesn't"?

Comment: English context for this: A: "I've never used a cellphone before." B: "Have you been living under a rock?"

Comment: you could make up your own version. maybe something like 明治時代以前に住んでいたら聞いたことないでしょう。でも....  i don't know, something creative perhaps.

Comment: `introducing a very basic thing to someone who probably should know about it...` 「まだ知らない人のために」とか「知らないと損をする！/ 知らない人は損してる！？」とか「今さら聞けない！？便利な機能」とかそんな感じ・・・？

Comment: Maybe「隠れ里に暮らしていたようならば」or 「隠れ里に暮らしていたようとしたら」? But I'm not a native speaker so I don't know what the tone of these would be or how it would come across, but 隠れ里 seems like a somewhat non-offensive term to me (correct me if I'm wrong!)

Answer (score 3):

Safe and common (but not funny) approaches are:

- 知らない人がるといけないので念のために紹介すると、（このアプリは…）
- ご存じの人が多いと思うが、（このアプリは…）
- 念のためだが、（このアプリは…）
- 周知のとおり、（このアプリは…）

AFAIK there is no common set phrase which is similar in purpose and funny at the same time. Of course you can always create your own funny expression, for example:

- 昭和からタイムスリップして来た人のために説明すると、（このアプリは…）
- 昨日まで10年山ごもりしていた人が読んでいるかもしれないので、一応解説しておくと、（このアプリは…）
- うちで飼っているインコでも当然知っている常識だが、（このアプリは…）

The "literal" translation of "in case you're living under a rock" would be:

- あなたが岩の下で生活している場合、（このアプリは…）

But this makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: what do you mean by AFAIK?